# Is it possible to extend Django's User model just adding objects to its model form?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create users with django's User Model but I want to add to it some extra boolean fields and choice fields. isn't there any way to do it without binding it with one to one field to another model?

I tried adding objects straight to User model and when I rendered the form I could see the fields I added but when it comes to admin panel, I can't see these fields.

Comment: No. There is no other ways since you want to *add* fields to database. And in your case, [extending with one to one field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) is the best option I think.

Comment: Maybe if you provide more context, we could help you more...

Comment: thank you so much, i think the only way is doing this and in views create two models when registering.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend the user model,

In your models.py file, create a new user model using

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
# Add your custom fields here
```

then set AUTH_USER_MODEL to "appname.CustomUser"

Run migrations

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: [Extend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) VS [Substitue](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)